# Get data from RotateTransform3D

Tags: c#, wpf, rotatetransform

i set my RotateTransform3D with this C# code:

```
rotation = new RotateTransform3D(
    new AxisAngleRotation3D(new Vector3D(0, 0, 1),
    Convert.ToDouble(5)),
    new Point3D(0, 0, 0)
);
```

how i get that "5" back?
if i do

```
MessageBox.Show(rotation.Rotation.toString())
```

it says `System.Windows.Media.Media3D.AxisAngleRotation3D` but the ".Rotation" should produce a `Rotation3D` object, like [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.media3d.rotatetransform3d.rotation.aspx) says.

How can i do that?

**Edit**: other information

in my code i set that `RotateTransform3D` as a children inside a `Transform3DGroup` with this:

```
myGroupArray[0].Children.Add(
    new RotateTransform3D(
        new AxisAngleRotation3D(new Vector3D(0, 0, 1),
        Convert.ToDouble(5)),
        new Point3D(0, 0, 0)
    )
);
```

and in another function i try to recover my "5" with this:

```
RotateTransform3D rotation = new RotateTransform3D();
rotation = (RotateTransform3D)myGroupArray[0].Children[0];
```

now, even doing

```
MessageBox.Show(rotation.Rotation.Angle.ToString());
```

results in error because `Rotation3D` does not contain an `Angle` property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it works with

```
MessageBox.Show((rotation.Rotation as AxisAngleRotation3D).Angle.ToString());
```

thanks to iTateSLC (from [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/d33068e6-4d9a-4178-ab1c-a7d0166806cc))for the solution :D

Answer (score 0):

The `5` you're passing in in the constructor of your `AxisAngleRotation3D` is the "Angle" like [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms602556.aspx) also says. Therefore you should be able to retrieve it from your Rotation as:

```
MessageBox.Show((rotation.Rotation as AxisAngleRotation3D).Angle.ToString());
```

`System.Windows.Media.Media3D.AxisAngleRotation3D` inherits from `Rotation3D` therefore it IS a `Rotation3D`.

EDIT: I missed that a cast would be required. The reason is that the `RotateTransform3D` class defines rotation as the base class of the `AxisAngleRotation3D` - which doesn't have the `Angle` property. Since you know you've created it using an actual `AxisAngleRotation3D` you can cast it to one.

Comment: visual studio says that Rotation3D doesn't contain an "angle" definition and mark it as error :( i update my code in main post! maybe i simplified too much!